# Vue's v-for does not show correct text for modal window (only displays the first item's data)

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

I'm using Vue (just started learning it) and Bootstrap to make a blog and I want a modal window (that shows the post's name/etc) to pop up when the user clicks on the comment button. However, right now the modal window only gets the post information from the latest blog post. This means that even if you click the 1st post, you would get the id information and post title of the latest one... Any suggestions or solutions? Thanks in advance!

It seems that the main problem with my code is that it makes n numbers of modals in vue if you have n posts. I have tried slots but the modals started displaying the first post instead of the last one. I wonder if all my modals are being displayed at once but I only the last one... Should I use an index instead?

Is there any way to make only one modal that gets and display the information of the post clicked?

Here's my code of the post component

```
Vue.component('posts', {
    props: ['post', 'loggedUser'],
    template: `
        <div class='blog-post py-2'>
            <h3> {{post.title}} </h3>
            <h6> Posted by {{post.postedBy}} on {{formatCompat(post.createdAt)}} </h6>
            <span class='comments'>
            <i class='far fa-comment-dots ml-3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal"></i>
            {{post.comments.length}}
            </span>
        </div>
    `
```

My modal component: (mostly from the bootstrap docs)

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    props: ['post'],
    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="commentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="commentModalLabel">Comment on {{post.postedBy}}'s post! ({{post.title}})</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
```

Here, I'd like the {{posted.title}} and other information to reflect the post where the comment button is clicked, but it's showing the latest post.

Parent element:

```
const postComponent = new Vue({
    el: '#posts',

    data: {
        posts: null
    },

    methods: { // mostly code unrelated to modal stuff

    }
```

My pug file:

```
 #posts
     if user                        
     posts(name=username, v-for='post in posts' v-bind:post='post' v-bind:key="post.id" v-on:like-post='like' logged-user=loggedUser v-on:comment-post='comment')
     modal(v-for='post in posts' v-bind:post='post' v-bind:key="post.id")
```

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I'm still not sure how to go about solving it. To open the modal, my comment button has the ```data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal"``` attributes, but in my template, it seems like I'm making n #commentModal ids. Thus, when the button is clicked, perhaps only the first modal is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom `data` property that reflects the selected post for the template to read.

```
data: {
 ...
   selected: '',
 ...
}
```

Then, you need a method that will assign the `selected` property to whichever post is clicked.

```
methods: {
    changeTitle(postId) {
      const currentPost = posts.filter((post) => {
         return post.id == postId;
      });
    this.selected = currentPost.id;
   }
}
```

So now that you have a data property to represent the current selected title, and a method to change that property with a click, you need to assign the directive for the method to the post. So, add this to the html tag you want to trigger the method:

```
@click = "changeTitle(postId);"
```

This will trigger the method along with the post id from the post that called the method. The current title can now be rendered anywhere in the template that has access to the data, like this:

```
{{selected}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I fixed my problem by dynamically binding ids like this: ```:data-target="'#post' + post._id"``` in my post template and in the modal template: ```:id="'post' + post._id"```. I guess it was just rendering the first id that had "commentModal". Your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: Ahh I see what you're doing. That's a good pattern also. Happy to help!